# Как добавить строки в таблицу в word (OpenXML)?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm, openxml

Сформировал примерный документ в ворде. Добавил шапку таблицы и несколько строк. Получил c# код при помощи проги OpenXML SDK2.0, в коде удалил созданные строки из таблицы кроме строки с шапкой.

[image: Нужный вид таблицы:]

Код:

```
//TableRow[] tableRow = new TableRow[selectedStudent.Questions.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < selectedStudent.Questions.Count; i++)
        {
            TableRow tableRow2 = new TableRow() { RsidTableRowAddition = "00954C83", RsidTableRowProperties = "00174B9E", ParagraphId = "199B0298", TextId = "77777777" };

            TableCell tableCell5 = new TableCell();

            TableCellProperties tableCellProperties5 = new TableCellProperties();
            TableCellWidth tableCellWidth5 = new TableCellWidth() { Width = "7508", Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa };

            tableCellProperties5.Append(tableCellWidth5);

            Paragraph paragraph5 = new Paragraph() { RsidParagraphMarkRevision = "00954C83", RsidParagraphAddition = "00954C83", RsidParagraphProperties = "00F26699", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00F26699", ParagraphId = "325F4E45", TextId = "5F466EE7" };

            ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties5 = new ParagraphProperties();
            Justification justification5 = new Justification() { Val = JustificationValues.Center };

            ParagraphMarkRunProperties paragraphMarkRunProperties5 = new ParagraphMarkRunProperties();
            RunFonts runFonts12 = new RunFonts() { Ascii = "Times New Roman", HighAnsi = "Times New Roman", ComplexScript = "Times New Roman" };
            FontSize fontSize12 = new FontSize() { Val = "24" };
            FontSizeComplexScript fontSizeComplexScript12 = new FontSizeComplexScript() { Val = "24" };

            paragraphMarkRunProperties5.Append(runFonts12);
            paragraphMarkRunProperties5.Append(fontSize12);
            paragraphMarkRunProperties5.Append(fontSizeComplexScript12);

            paragraphProperties5.Append(justification5);
            paragraphProperties5.Append(paragraphMarkRunProperties5);

            Run run8 = new Run();

            RunProperties runProperties8 = new RunProperties();
            RunFonts runFonts13 = new RunFonts() { Ascii = "Times New Roman", HighAnsi = "Times New Roman", ComplexScript = "Times New Roman" };
            FontSize fontSize13 = new FontSize() { Val = "24" };
            FontSizeComplexScript fontSizeComplexScript13 = new FontSizeComplexScript() { Val = "24" };

            runProperties8.Append(runFonts13);
            runProperties8.Append(fontSize13);
            runProperties8.Append(fontSizeComplexScript13);
            Text text5 = new Text();
            text5.Text = selectedStudent.Questions.First().Question;

            run8.Append(runProperties8);
            run8.Append(text5);

            paragraph5.Append(paragraphProperties5);
            paragraph5.Append(run8);

            tableCell5.Append(tableCellProperties5);
            tableCell5.Append(paragraph5);

            TableCell tableCell6 = new TableCell();

            TableCellProperties tableCellProperties6 = new TableCellProperties();
            TableCellWidth tableCellWidth6 = new TableCellWidth() { Width = "2336", Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa };
            Shading shading1 = new Shading() { Val = ShadingPatternValues.Clear, Color = "auto", Fill = "00B050" };

            tableCellProperties6.Append(tableCellWidth6);
            tableCellProperties6.Append(shading1);

            Paragraph paragraph6 = new Paragraph() { RsidParagraphMarkRevision = "00954C83", RsidParagraphAddition = "00954C83", RsidParagraphProperties = "00F26699", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00954C83", ParagraphId = "0D4A70E1", TextId = "77777777" };

            ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties6 = new ParagraphProperties();
            Justification justification6 = new Justification() { Val = JustificationValues.Center };

            ParagraphMarkRunProperties paragraphMarkRunProperties6 = new ParagraphMarkRunProperties();
            RunFonts runFonts14 = new RunFonts() { Ascii = "Times New Roman", HighAnsi = "Times New Roman", ComplexScript = "Times New Roman" };
            FontSize fontSize14 = new FontSize() { Val = "24" };
            FontSizeComplexScript fontSizeComplexScript14 = new FontSizeComplexScript() { Val = "24" };

            paragraphMarkRunProperties6.Append(runFonts14);
            paragraphMarkRunProperties6.Append(fontSize14);
            paragraphMarkRunProperties6.Append(fontSizeComplexScript14);

            paragraphProperties6.Append(justification6);
            paragraphProperties6.Append(paragraphMarkRunProperties6);

            paragraph6.Append(paragraphProperties6);

            tableCell6.Append(tableCellProperties6);
            tableCell6.Append(paragraph6);
            table1.Append(tableRow2);
        }
```

Если создание TableRow и всего остального выношу из цикла, то после компиляции строка появляется в нужном  виде и месте в вордвоском документе. Собственно, в этом вопрос, как динамически добавлять строки в таблицу?

Comment: ну так вам уже сгенерирован пример. Создаёте строку, ячейки, прикрепляете к таблице. В цикле делаете это сколько нужно раз. У вас всё есть. В чем проблема?

Comment: Единственное: возможно, перед table1.Append(tableRow2); вы пропустили tableRow2.Append(tableCell6);

Comment: @Нетерпеливыйигуан спасибо, за Вашу внимательность, действительно в этом оказалось проблема! Если есть желание, то оформите ответ, и Вам зачтётся.)

Comment: восстановил ответ, прост сперва удалил его.. подумал, что проблема глубже)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, перед `table1.Append(tableRow2);` вы пропустили `tableRow2.Append(tableCell6);`

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь. Я тоже думал, что проблема глубже.)